# About "Is this allowed" type of questions

Tags: discussion, scope

I just want to know why this question was put on hold:

[Is there any provision of 'Divorce' concept in Hindusm? [on hold]](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2979/93)

In my opinion, there are many questions on Hinduism.SE which are similar to the above question. I found some on quick search:

- [Are drugs allowed in Hinduism?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/14/93)
- [Are women allowed to be Hindu sanyasis/monks?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/706/93)
- [What does Hinduism say on multiple marriages?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/557/93)
- [Does Hinduism forbid sexual intercourse before marriage?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/916/93)

Why is this out of scope?

I might be wrong but my personal opinion is that it should be on-topic because it is about knowing Hinduism whether it allows Divorce or not.

**PS**: This question was also closed as off-topic:

- [Is dating allowed? [on hold]](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2975/93)

but I think it should get close as duplicate of

- [Does Hinduism forbid sexual intercourse before marriage?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/916/93)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### It's all about quality now

If users still want to welcome such types of questions, then I can't really alone make this site graduate. If you look at the questions on other religion sites, they are much more quality ones compared to ours.

Coming to the question and why did I put the question on hold?

Reason : Unclear (And not off-topic, there's a difference)

It was about **divorce** - According to me this is started in modern era where couple signs off their papers and break their marriages so its highly possible that granths will never mention about divorce.

So why closed as unclear?
The question was more of a law thing instead of religion. Hinduism doesn't make provisions, its law which makes provisions. If you don't believe me, search for the words *divorce*, and *hinduism* and [see what you get](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=hinduism%20divorce). Reframing the question with the words separation, sins etc may sound more clear.

---

**Coming to the second question**

*but I think it should get close as duplicate of*

**NO**, if you think that it should be closed as  a duplicate then your views for *dating* is wrong. Dating is not sexual intercourse, dating is just a casual meet where a girl meets a boy, they may visit a restaurant, chit chat, and they leave for home. So do you think granth will really explain abut dating now?

---

**What's the issue now?**

If users are supporting these kind of questions, then at some point I may hesitate to close them as at the end of the day others will reopen and support such questions anyways. Result could be?

- Site not graduating for years
- [You all will get the site zipped with XML where you'll get all questions and answers of the site and site will be ultimately closed.](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11624/freelance-workers)

Why I tend to close the above two questions is because they are discussing somewhat modern era actions. It is similar to me asking questions like :-

- Can I kill other players in a PC Game? Does our scriptures say anything about this?
- Can we watch porn? Does scriptures say anything about this?
- Can I visit a Pole Dancing Club? Does scriptures say anything on this?

I could just go on and on and on... So do you think that scriptures will really explain whether an individual should visit a pole dancing club? Divorce is somewhat similar to this and so is the dating question. If you accept these questions right now, it is likely that someone will ask such questions which I shared and if you close it, he will take examples of the questions you shared and will say that if you reopened this then why not mine?

As we all know that the rules will be changed for a particular phase. It's like balancing out the crap vs the good.

**What am expecting?**

I am now expecting questions which are just excellent ones, not only helpful, but which makes sense in asking and understanding, which shares real knowledge of our scriptures.

Asking questions of "[What is](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/search?q=what%20is)" and "[say about](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/search?q=say%20about)" will never help the site get better.

I would like to see some questions like :-

Pick any question of [this user](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/36/keshav-srinivasan?tab=questions) and see how different they are from others. Unlike other questions its not asking in one or two lines, he researches, he explains and he asks for an answer. Obviously he has What is and say about type questions but they are far more better then most of the questions asked on the site. Apart from that here's my list of excellent questions :-

- [Is the ultimate purpose of life only to serve God?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2989/is-the-ultimate-purpose-of-life-is-only-to-serve-god)
- [How to identify Valampuri Sangu (conch shell)?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2933/how-to-identify-valampuri-sangu-conch-shell)
- [Conflict between Bhagwad Gita & Garuda Puran regarding the Atma/Soul](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2913/conflict-between-bhagwad-gita-garuda-puran-regarding-the-atma-soul)
- [Is Janeva (Yajñopavītam or sacred thread) limited to Brahmins only?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2892/is-janeva-limited-to-brahmins)
- [How does Karma work for a person who has converted to Hinduism?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2886/how-does-karma-work-for-a-person-who-has-converted-to-hinduism)
- [Is our destiny predetermined? If yes, then why do our actions affect our karma?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2399/is-our-destiny-pre-determined-if-yes-then-why-do-our-actions-affect-our-karma) (It's my own so don't take it in a wrong way)

So I hope users get my point as I've explained well enough. So if you are voting, be it anything, up or down, so read the answer first and don't just vote and run away, voting matters as it shows whether you are supporting the decisions on meta or not, if no time to read then you should move to next answer straight away.

If you downvote, please explain whats wrong with the decision and please suggest an alternative.

Comment: I agree with all your mentioned points above. but I think this question is exceptional and can be made valid by rephrasing like "What does Hinduism say about splitting after marriage?" (_could be rephrased better I think_) though the question is not high quality it could be made valid on this site. because using "divorce" word is related to law which I agree.

Comment: Thanks for praising my questions.  I put a lot of work into writing each one.  I 10000% agree that people should ask more questions like the ones that I ask and fewer "what does Hinduism say about X?" questions.

Comment: I find disturbing that the answers to "Is the ultimate purpose of life is only to serve God?" are 4/6 opinions without any scriptural references. At which point do we delete answers that are clearly just opinion? Jabahar's top answer is the only good one.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Congrats on becoming the Jon Skeet of hinduism.stackexchange.com!

Comment: @Akshay Sorry, who's Jon Skeet?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan [Jon Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) is the most famous StackOverflow user and has a mind-boggling 700k rep.

Comment: _"According to me this is started in modern era where couple signs off their papers and break their marriages so its highly possible that granths will never mention about divorce."_ I disagree on this. And I didn't read the rest carefully. I would read complete later and will then vote.

Comment: I think there should be a balance. Too many of 'what does Hinduism say about' will lead to reduced quality. Whereas banning all less than perfect questions (and answers) will lead to one question a week, which also would lead to closing the site. (I voted up just to appreciate the detailed thinking process and caring for Hinduism stack excahnge)

Comment: @Sai thank you for appreciating, also users are having a wrong impression of the site being closed if not much content is contributed. SE asks for quality first, so even if users ask 15 questions a day but they are of low quality, site will be eventually closed, no matter what amount of questions you have, if you want, check http://judaism.stackexchange.com, less content, quality content and their site is noe graduated.

Comment: Also lets not forget their area51, they graduated in a year and see the stats http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/22435/mi-yodeya

Comment: @Mr.Alien Thanks for sharing that info! It is clear that quality is more important. I was just pointing out that having an iron fist and requiring all questions to be perfect and nothing less than that would also be detrimental (however now that is not the case as all moderators are doing a great job :) ). But overall I totally agree with whatever you have mentioned.