# Progress report for the site

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

Few days back a user posted a question on meta which asked "Where do we stand?" and was deleted later by himself, so I thought to post one about the sites progress. You can also [refer another post of mine](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/310/124) before reading this question.

Currently, am feeling glad to say that the site is going smooth, more users are now actively participating in some or the other ways.

Statistics for the website are not good enough yet but we can fix it together. I'll list down the things which are going right on the site and should be continued, and things which aren't going good and should be done.

Good things first :

- Users are flagging low quality answers, spam answers (excellent part)
- Editing posts
- Closing off-topic posts
- Answering questions in detail (Well, most of the time)
- Am analyzing the data for the site, and we are getting good amount of traffic via search engine and this is a very good point
- Users are commenting when they flag which gives some time to the users to edit their answer (again a good point)
- Scope for the site is almost clear

Things we should work on :

- Still, some users are posting *Significance* type questions so we should get a step ahead and ask more meaningful questions
- Lack of professionals
- Please Please take care of your English when you write
- Vote (Upvote or Downvote), am seeing some of the best users on the site are not voting the low quality content, and they are not appreciating quality answers by upvoting them, so please do so, won't cost you any reputation, and you are on a religious site, don't play foul.
- Properly tag your questions
- Stay active on meta, raise issues, suggest ideas, actively participate in group discussions
- Stay active in chat rooms

So if we see, most of the things are going pretty good, we need to work a little more on few things and site will be a nice place to visit for others.

Apart from the above points, I would like the users to edit their old answers if they find that they had posted some low quality answers which are correct in a way but aren't deleted as we had experienced a delay for getting our mods elected for the site. So this way, we will have nice answers, and it will also help you with your knowledge part.

Any comments, questions if I've not covered in my question, feel free to post as answers.

Comment: You should link to your previous answer concerning the question quality issue: http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/310/36

Comment: Also useful is this stat about our Hinduism page http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/53689/hinduism.

Comment: @Sai Dont worry much about statistics, Stackexchange looks for quality, not quantity...

Comment: I think it's time for the next progress report for the site :)

Comment: @Sai I am planning to write one but after February :) lets see though