# Progress report for the site II

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

I wanted to post this in the first week of March but I wanted to analyze things perfectly out here and also I was bit busy since a month hence got delayed.

Lets take a look at the analytics here <sup>As of (**22<sup>nd</sup> March 2015**)</sup>  :-

```
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| Questions | Answers | Answered | Users | Visitors/Day |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
|   1,196   |  1,790  |    80%   | 1,579 |    2,416     |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

Sweet, as I see, everything is showing + compared to the last time I posted a [progress report](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320/progress-report-for-the-site). Now here I'll share some good parts and some bad parts compared to the previous progress report/status.

What are the **Good parts** :-

- Increasing number of visitors and new users signing up
- Many people are getting regular on the site
- We got a new active mod
- Questions are searched over the internet thus shows we are asking meaningful content out here

and what are **Bad** ones :-

- User's lack of knowledge and copy pasting behavior, though this has reduced because of the rule we made where the answers of the users will be deleted if they are totally copy pasted but still this issue hangs around so need to fix it. If you see such answers been posted, please notify a moderator to take a look at it and we will take an action for the same.
- Lack of professionals. This issue is haunting us since day 1, we do have professionals but still we are lacking in number. Obviously site is not THAT old that I expect thousands of pro's for this topic but still we need some. Fix for this was proposed by [@Ankit Sharma](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/363/124). So we will decide few things for that and get started shortly.
- Crappyness all around the site. When you flag for a low quality answer or a comment been not constructive, please leave another comment on the answer or a reply to the non constructive comment which explains them where they went wrong. If the answer is low quality, we will comment before delete but it will get easy if you as a user leave a comment on the answer which will explain the user before we take any action and also it will be helpful to us as a reference to your flag.
- Rudeness : Recently I've seen users posting on meta getting pissed off by moderators actions so I would like to say not to do so. Moderators job is to keep the site clean, now obviously moderators can go wrong as they are humans and not robots. If you are not happy with a particular action, instead of public shaming you can simply ask a general question on meta discussing about an action or you can discuss with a moderator in chat room. Also, some users are using foul words in private mod messages which won't be tolerated and stringent action will be taken against that user. We all are one family, its just that moderators are appointed to run things smooth in the family, but if any member is upset, he can discuss it freely but not via public shaming or using abusive words. Moderators are not paid for their jobs, they do it so that others get optimum content out of the site.
- Need answered ratio to increase, it did increased up by few % but still it's low. To fix this issue, I would recommend users who are pretty good with the topic to dig out some old posts, edit them, and answer them if you know. If the questions are too broad or they are unclear, close vote and comment out to help the OP which suggests what he/she should fix in order to get an answer from the community.
- **Vote**, this won't cost you any reputation except for downvoting (non wiki)answers. Vote the users who put real efforts in answering questions of yours and others. Respect the time they have invested in research/studies of this topic. Voting also shares positivity amongst users, will encourage them to post more and write more quality content.
- Last but not the least, don't forget to mark the answer as accepted(correct) if it is, that will also help future visitors of what they should refer to.

That said, I think pretty much is stable as of now, if you have any questions over this or some behavior / point which I am missing out, feel free to answer and discuss.

Comment: It should be featured in community bulletin.

Comment: I'd add one more item to your list: we need to encourage people to post better questions.  If people start more asking questions that are well-researched and based on something in Hindu scripture, rather than vague "What does Hinduism say about X?" type questions, that could go a long way to attracting experts.

Comment: So, when can we expect a stable site?

Comment: @Mr_Green When there is no BAD section in my progress report

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Yes that is an issue as well, but I think recently questions are making some sense.

Comment: That will definitely take lot of effort and time. I hope I will be around at that time. :)

Comment: I really like the way this site is being professionally managed by Mr.Alien and @KeshavSrinivasan :). I just have one suggestion and that is to improve the way new users are welcomed to the site. Right now it seems that they are always bombed with 'how their answers dont fit into the site'. :) That would help them to feel welcome and continue participating. All the best.

Comment: @Sai Thanks for the kind words!  As far as new users go, are you talking about new users' questions or new users' answers?  Concerning answers, what I generally do is say something like "Welcome to Hinduism.SE! Answers on this site should be elaborated with details and sources (preferably scripture).  They shouldn't just be one line long; otherwise you should wait until you have enough reputation to post comments.  So I'm deleting your answer and converting it to a comment.  If you want to expand your answer, then edit it and flag me to undelete it." Do you suggest we respond differently?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Questions I think are fine. But whenever a new user wants to answer a question it seems like the experts are always trying to tell Him what he should be doing. I do like your comments overall. But IMHO I would also put in some encouraging words like 'Welcome to Hinduism.SE your thoughts are very good and we appreciate your participation. Here are some guidelines (link X) to create great answers. We encourage answers which have some citations rather than just opinions. Welcome. All the best.' Something like that. But hey it is just a suggestion. Overall all of you are briliant

Comment: @Sai Thanks!  Yeah, I could put more nice things into the messages, to give new users more encouragement.

Comment: I would only ask that when a new user, who appears to be non-Hindu, asks a question we give them some leeway and encourage them as to online resources to their question, how to correctly phase their question, or specifically tell them why their question is not appropriate to the site. There is an old tradition that guests who appear at your door should be treated as Narayana. On the internet we should do the same. A person should not feel the door was slammed in their face, they should walk away feeling satisfied.

Comment: @Mr.Alien when we can expect the next progress report. I think it can address all newly enthusiastic meta participation into right direction.

Comment: What about `Progress report for the site III` after one year?

Comment: @Pandya http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/598/help-us-out-to-make-this-site-better?cb=1 ?

Comment: @Mr.Alien oh! ok; I also thinking that but just asked as the title isn't saying that...

Comment: @Mr.Alien please rename that post to progress report. It is mis-guiding to some users as you can see in comments.