# Why is this question considered off-topic?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/34012/is-it-a-sin-to-kill-people-in-video-games).

This question is not off-topic. It is asking if a particular action is a sin, and the question which actions are sinful is relevant to Hinduism. Just because the question has the words "video games" in it does not make it off-topic.

This question is very relevant today since many people play first-person shooters. For example, according to [this article](https://www.destructoid.com/why-do-the-kids-love-call-of-duty--204608.phtml), an 8 year old boy likes Call of Duty because of the killing:

> "I love that game! I LOVE IT SO MUCH," said the eight-year-old. I asked him what he liked about it. **"The killing..."** he said, in a sing-song, matter-of-fact tone.

My pet theory is that since it's the Kali Yuga, many people have Rakshasa and Paisacha tendencies and enjoy killing people for fun and satisfy that desire through violent video games.

Comment: I am repeating my comment here - If somebody had asked - "is it a sin to play porn video games?", at least some people here would have answered yes. So why is this question about virtual killing not permitted?

Comment: Strongly related, but asked from different perspective: [About “Is this allowed” type of questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/309/2461)

Comment: Hindu Scriptures don't mention modern concepts like Video Games. It will produce speculated and opinion based answers.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Then I shall use an ancient example that is analogous to video games. This is done in court.

Answer (score -1):

The question(s) whose answers can be implied from the scriptural claims or statements shouldn't be considered off topic. One could arrive at the answer of your question easily through implications from scriptural/religious content.

This site shouldn't become herd of sentient bots who ain't interested in brainstorming while dealing with an answer, but mere interested in bombarding 'answer section' with crude scriptural paragraphs.

PS: Yeah, it is adharma & clear violence according to sanAtana ways of life. I liked your way of thinking.